# Don't see models in db.sqlite3(Python, Django)

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to make a custom user model using, abstract user, but yet can't see them on DB.
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/condescending-archimedes-h7lx22?file=%2Fsettings.py%3A158%2C23

I used abstract user to modify the original User class. I then procced to make a seralizer, did migrations(without any errors), and then added the AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'base.CustomUser' to settings.py.
And still I don't see the models on the DB file.
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/condescending-archimedes-h7lx22?file=%2Fsettings.py%3A158%2C23

Comment: Paste your code in your question please.

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: how to ask a good question:
[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)